# cant install wordpress pulgins and theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMHWl.jpg)

check the image this error come every plugin and theme I tried to install

Comment: Is this a completely fresh installation? If so, how was the installation done?

Comment: yes the installation was complete and one more thing i think its the problem with my wifi connection because i pluged my phone internet to my pc everything worked perfectly  any ideas

Comment: Assuming the issues are persistent, I'd say the first thing to do if you haven't already is to check for the email explaining issues and to follow the link to "learn more about debugging in WordPress." Even if the issues clear themselves up, I still might be curious about debugging info if there's any available.

Comment: hi so I install WordPress on a domain and it work fine but it does work on my localhost  think the problem is with my local hos